# Minting a NFT (collection) with Blockfrost

Tags: nft, minting, development, blockfrost, developers

I see al lot of NFT projects where you can buy 1 or multiple NFT's for a certain price. Like unsigned_algorithms, CardanoTrees etc. I am curious how these projects are created without the use of smart contracts, is it something that can be done using Blockfrost?

Comment: I am not an expert but I think you can't mint NFTs with Blockfrost and maybe never will.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need blockfrost, just learn the cardano-cli and you can make anything. https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/minting-nfts/

Download the [Testnet version of Daedalus](https://testnets.cardano.org/en/testnets/cardano/get-started/wallet/) and get [tADA (Test ADA)](https://testnets.cardano.org/en/testnets/cardano/tools/faucet/) from the faucet and practice making them.

I also recommend looking at nftmaker pro for quickly minting your own NFT collection. https://www.nft-maker.io/

Answer (score 3):

We can mint NFTs on cardano without smart contracts. There are some projects which help to do it in a browser like https://namiwallet.io/, but you can do it via CLI

Answer (score 1):

The main reason that we can mint NFTs without smart contracts is native tokens on the Cardano blockchain.
A good explanation is found here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccLgnM3ErUE at around 3 minutes.
There are multiple websites out there now that can take care of the minting process for you.
For example: https://metromermaids.com/mint/v0.104/ or https://www.nft-maker.io/ as well as various NFT marketplaces now also offering token minting support.

Answer (score 0):

you just need :

1. cardano CLI to mint NFT
2. cardano node to be connected with the rest of the network
3. Cardano wallet :) for payment address
4. blockfrost to find info about Cardano blockchain, in case of sales, you need to find the Address of the wallet, which paid for your NFT
5. IPFS for Storage decentralize solution
6. some ubuntu / programming / scripting knowledge, for automation sales machine :)

enjoy decentralization and Digital art!!!

theTokenSquare17

pool operator for TTS17 pool